# Bukkit : Read out Custom Name String / Extract Integer

Tags: java, bukkit

I am currently working on a little RPG-Plugin, and at the moment I am trying to read out the Level of a mob which is summoned via the following code:

```
public static void summonMob(EntityType entTy, int level, World w, Location loc) {

    Entity en = w.spawnEntity(loc, entTy);
    en.setCustomName(ChatColor.RED + "Experiment One " + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "> " + ChatColor.GREEN + level
            + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " <");
}
```

And then called in the onEnable() for testing:

```
summonMob(EntityType.ZOMBIE, 1, w, new Location(w, 238, 45, 1349));
```

The "test-mob" was summoned with the Level 1, I am trying to read out this information in the following event:

```
@EventHandler
public void onEntityDeath(EntityDeathEvent e) {
    if (e.getEntity().getKiller() instanceof Player) {

        Player p = e.getEntity().getKiller();

        if (e.getEntity().getCustomName() != null) {

            int mobLevel = Integer
                    .parseInt(ChatColor.stripColor(e.getEntity().getCustomName().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "")
                            .replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]+", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "")));
            p.sendMessage("You've slain a Level " + mobLevel + " enemie!");
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is, although all non-digits are removed from the custom name, the final integer always adds two times the "8", making 818 out of 1, and 8208 out of 20.

I've probably missed something simple here, and it would be great if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While storing a mobs level inside its name, it can make its extraction hard when using it. A better solution may be using Bukkit's [Metadatable](https://jd.bukkit.org/index.html?org/bukkit/metadata/Metadatable.html) system.

This system is really easy to use and can be done with the following:

When you spawn you mob, you attach a value to the mob in the following way:

```
en.setMetadata("level", new FixedMetadataValue(level));
```

When the mob is slaim, you can easily extract the value back by doing:

```
List<MetadataValue> data = e.getEntity().getMetadata("level");
if(data.isEmpty()) return;
int level = data.get(0).asInt();
```

That way, you don't need to do complex string regexes to get your level back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use net.minecraft.server code to create custom entities, yet this is problematic when dealing with minecraft updates as the function names will most likely change due to obfuscation.

You could just go and decompile the bukkit release you're using and take a look at the bukkit classes "Entitie" and those related to it, search through them and try to figure out what they mean or google a bit for "bukkit <release> entitie nms", that might help you as well.

This would also allow you to easily run custom code on your entities, manipulate pathfinding, behaviour, let them react to chat/commands, let them chat and run commands, <blahbla>...

I'll look for my CustomVillager as soon as I get home as I'm on the fly now and have all that kind of stuff on my big storage at home but I'll edit it in ASAP

Comment: Thanks! As I am not allowed yet to upvote posts, I had to choose Ferrybig's solution, as it was quicker to apply :3